# How to see that equalities follow from summation by parts?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation, power-series, summation-by-parts

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $s_n = a_0+...+a_n$. The following equalities appear in a proof I'm reading

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n &= a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (s_n - s_{n-1})x^n\\
&= (1-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_nx^n \\
&= (1-x)^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (s_0+...+s_n)x^n.
\end{align}

The first equality is clear and the second two are said to follow from [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts). I guess I'm missing something very basic, but I don't see how to get the last two equalities using summation by parts. Could someone explain this, or at least give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $c_n=s_n$ and $d_n=x^n$, summation by parts says that (as formal power series) $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(d_{n+1}-d_n)=-c_0d_0-\sum_{n=1}^\infty (c_n-c_{n-1})d_n.$$
The left side is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n(x^{n+1}-x^n)=(x-1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_nx^n$$ and the right side is $$-a_0-\sum_{n=1}^\infty (s_n-s_{n-1})x^n,$$ so negating both sides gives your second equality.

For the third equality you can do the same thing, just with $c_n=s_0+\dots+s_n$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^k s_nx^n=&\sum_{n=0}^k s_nx^n-\sum_{n=0}^k s_nx^{n+1}\\=&a_0+\sum_{n=1}^k s_nx^n-\sum_{n=1}^{k+1} s_{n-1}x^n\\=&a_0+\sum_{n=1}^k (s_n-s_{n-1})x^n-s_kx^{k+1}
\end{align*}
Now let $k\to\infty$.